# How to display all the records from the elastic search. I'm able to retrieve exactly 3 records from database, Elastic Search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

There are 18 records under a company but I can see only 3 records from them. Below is my query and the python code.

```
{
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "inner_hits": {
            "_source": [
              "name",
              "country",
              "_matched_experiences.role"
            ]
          },
          "path": "socials",
          "query": {
            "match": { "socials._has_email": "true"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "_source": [
        "com_name"
      ]
      }
```

Below is my python code.

```
with open(OUTPUT_FILENAME_1, "a") as f1:
        csv_writer_1 = csv.writer(f1)
        csv_writer_1.writerow(["company_name","name","country","role"])
        query_dictionary = {above query}

        scroll = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(es, query=query_dictionary, index=companydirectory, scroll='60m', size=800)
        for res in scroll:
            try:
                record_fields = res["_source"]  
                name = ""
                com_name = ""
                company_name = record_fields.get("com_name")  #from the ES
                name_record_fields = res["inner_hits"]["social_contacts"]["hits"]["hits"]
                for j in name_record_fields:
                    name = j['_source']['name']    #from ES
                    k = j['_source']['_matched_experiences']
                    role = k[0].get('role')
                    country = j['_source']['country']
                    print company_name,name,validated_email_fromES, function_id,level_id, country, company_name,role
                    # csv_writer_1.writerow([company_name.encode('utf8'),name.encode('utf8'),country,role.encode('utf8')])  

            except Exception as e1:
                pass
```

This is the sample output from ES :

```
  "_source": {
    "company_name": "Rothborns"
    },
    "inner_hits": {
    "social_contacts": {
    "hits": {
    "total": 18,
    "max_score": 9.87977,
    "hits": [
    {
    "_type": "comp_directory",
    "_id": "MC9MY",
    "_nested": {
    "field": "socials",
    "offset": 36
    },
    "_score": 9.787,
    "_source": {
    "country": "SA",
    "name": "warner Pauli",
    "_has_email": true,
    "_matched_experiences": [
    {
    "role": "Financial Controller"
    }
    ]
    }
```

The total record is 18 in Rothborns. But I can get only 3 records from Rothborns in the output file.

Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because when using `inner_hits` [the size is 3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#_options) by default. You simply need to change your query to this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "inner_hits": {
        "size": 100,                  <--- add this
        "_source": [
          "name",
          "country",
          "_matched_experiences.role"
        ]
      },
      "path": "socials",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "socials._has_email": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "com_name"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Val. I have a doubt, If suppose a company has more than 100 employees how can I collect them ? Is there any possibility like "size":all ?

Comment: Also I get an error **elasticsearch.helpers.ScanError: Scroll request has failed on 2 shards out of 40**

Comment: By default, the maximum size you can get is 10000, which would suffice for most companies I guess.

Comment: The error you get is unrelated to the query, otherwise it would fail on all  shards. It must be something else.

Comment: Besides, if you have 100+ nested employee documents, the `nested` type is probably not a wise choice. You should look towards the parent/child relationship or even better simply denormalize your documents.

Comment: Default size is 10000 or 3 ? I'm new to ES and I have few confusions on the nested size and size of the document. Then what does size : 100 does ?
Kindly help me understand.

Comment: By default 3 nested inner hits are returned if no size is specified. If size is specified, you can only go up to 10000 nested docs. 10000 is the default **maximum** value which can be raised if needed, but again, if you land in that situation, you should probably revise your data model.

Comment: Oh.Got it. Thanks Val for your time. :)

Comment: Hi Val. Can you help me telling whether my the scroll in the python code is correct ? Because if i remove the "size":100 and run the code, it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Looks ok to me, try to change the size to various numbers and see where it itches.

Comment: Okay. Sure :) I shall try